# Runtime translation in Angular

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular6

In my app I'm trying to add Localization. I have achieved using **i18n** with `.xlf` file and **l10n** with `.json` file by adding same values in different languages.

**For eg**: I am having an `.xlf` file contains "Hello" in English and another `.xlf` file having `Hola` in Spanish by using this, I am loading these values into my component when user switches the language from English to Spanish.

Is there any ways to achieve the same by run-time without adding those files.

Comment: If you are open to using third party libraries, you should check out ngx-translate (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core)

Comment: Yes @sah1 this example is good one, but I need any API to translate my application.